# Não consigo por o ícone do lado direito da tela, dentro de uma div

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="row-md-12 container-fluid" id="rodape">
    <p style="color: white;padding-top: 7px;"> Siga-nos! </p>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloca o ícone dentro do parágrafo.

Observações:

- A tag `<i>` será afetada pelo cor definida no `<p>`, portanto, eu coloquei `color: initial` no `<i>`, outra alternativa é utilizar `<span>`;
- Mudei a cor do texto para vermelho, para conseguirmos visualizar;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row-md-12 container-fluid" id="rodape">
  <p style="color: red;padding-top: 7px;"> 
    ícone a direita >  
    <i style="color:initial" class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="row-md-12 container-fluid" id="rodape">
  <p style="padding-top:7px;"> 
    <i  class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
    <span style="color: red;"> < ícone a esquerda </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar a tag `<i>` dentro da tag `<p>`. Como `<i>` tem display inline ele se mantem na mesma linha.

Para mover o rodape para a direita basta apenas alterar sua position para `relative` e adicionar `right: 0;` assim ele se mantera a direita.

```css
#rodape {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-md-12 container-fluid" id="rodape">
    <p style="color: black;padding-top: 7px;  "> 
    Siga-nos! <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
    </p>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a classe `d-inline` nativa do Bootstrap (**[documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)**). Irá converter a tag `<p>` em um elemento *inline* e o elemento seguinte (no caso, o ícone) irá se alinhar logo ao lado:

```css
*{
   background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row-md-12 container-fluid" id="rodape">
   <p class="d-inline" style="color: white;padding-top: 7px;"> Siga-nos! </p>
   <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
</div>
```